# How to get to know that new user is logged in using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have implemented spring security and I can get all the logged in user by using the following code and display them under online tag

```
 for (Object user: sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
            User onlineUser = (User) user;
            onlineUsersIds.add(onlineUser.getId());
         }
```

Is this possible to know that a user is just logged in so that I can update the online users list or I have to check sessionRegistry on every 5 or 10 minutes and then update user list every 5 or 10 minutes.

Please let me know if you need any other detail.

Answer (score 1):

i would use this: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html

this would be on a 'per session' basis.

so everytime someone is authenticated, spring security puts certain values inside the session.

what you do is, check for that session attribute with the 'valueBound' and 'valueUnbound' methods.
these methods would get an application scoped 'set' or synchronized 'set' process them accordingly

everytime you render a page, you just read from the application scoped set

Comment: Hi Titi, thanks for your response. Could you please show some example for this I tried to implement the above interface but then don't know how to call valueBound and ValueUnound methods and what to pass as parameters inside these methods.

Comment: Hi, you don't have to call the methods. It is a listener. It will be called when an event happens.